# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. In the code, "pembekal" means supplier. when I click the button "New stok"- it will create new books or other new items, but it give the error as below:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'stok_create' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['books/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/create/$']
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Pembekal(models.Model):
    pembekal = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    alamat = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.pembekal

class Stok(models.Model):
    stok = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    pembekal = models.ForeignKey(Pembekal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stoks')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.jenis_stok
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Pembekal
from .forms import PembekalForm, StokForm

def pembekal_list(request):
    pembekals = Pembekal.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'books/book_list.html', {'pembekals': pembekals})

def stok_list(request, pk):
    pembekal = Pembekal.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'books/stok_list.html', {'pembekal':pembekal})

def save_pembekal_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            pembekals = Pembekal.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_list.html', {'pembekals': pembekals})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def pembekal_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PembekalForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = PembekalForm()
    return save_pembekal_form(request, form, 'books/includes/partial_book_create.html')

def save_stok_form(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            stoks = Stok.objects.all()
            data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_stok_list.html', {'stoks': stoks})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def stok_create(request, pk):
    pembekal = get_object_or_404(Pembekal, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StokForm(request.POST, instance=pembekal)
    else:
        form = StokForm(instance=pembekal)
    return save_stok_form(request, form, 'books/includes/partial_stok_create.html')

def pembekal_update(request, pk):
    pembekal = get_object_or_404(Pembekal, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PembekalForm(request.POST, instance=pembekal)
    else:
        form = PembekalForm(instance=pembekal)
    return save_pembekal_form(request, form, 'books/includes/partial_book_update.html')

def pembekal_delete(request, pk):
    pembekal = get_object_or_404(Pembekal, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pembekal.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        pembekals = Pembekal.objects.all()
        data['html_book_list'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_list.html',
        {'pembekals': pembekals})
    else:
        context = {'pembekal': pembekal}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('books/includes/partial_book_delete.html',
        context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Pembekal, Stok


class PembekalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pembekal
        fields = ('pembekal', 'alamat', 'telefon',)

class StokForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stok
        fields = ('stok',)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
        path('books/', views.pembekal_list, name='book_list'),
        path('books/create/', views.pembekal_create, name='book_create'),
        path('books/<int:pk>/', views.stok_list, name='stok_list'),
        path('books/<int:pk>/update/', views.pembekal_update, name='book_update'),
        path('books/<int:pk>/delete/', views.pembekal_delete, name='book_delete'),
        path('books/<int:pk>/create/', views.stok_create, name='stok_create'),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

stok_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block javascript %}
  <script src="{% static 'books/js/books.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}        
  <div class="container">
    <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'book_list' %}">Pembekals</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{ pembekal.pembekal }}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-create-book" data-url="{% url 'stok_create' pk=pembekal.pk %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      New stok
    </button>
  </p>

  <table class="table" id="book-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Stok</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% include 'books/includes/partial_stok_list.html' %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-book">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

partial_stok_create.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'stok_create' pk=pembekal.pk %}" class="js-book-create-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new stok</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% include 'books/includes/partial_stok_form.html' %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create stok</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

partial_stok_form.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

partial_stok_list.html

```
{% for stok in pembekal.stoks.all %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ stok.id }}</td>
    <td><a href="#">{{ stok.stok }}</a></td>
    <td style="width: 150px">
      <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-warning btn-sm js-update-book"
              data-url="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
      </button>
      <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-danger btn-sm js-delete-book"
              data-url="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% empty %}
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" class="text-center bg-warning">No book</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

That's all the files I used at the moment. Any helps is greatly appreciated. I'm using Ajax to render to CRUD app. The modal form isn't pop up due to the above message. There may be mistakes in multiples files. Please do correct me. Thanks

Comment: Show the code for the view that renders `stok_list.html`. It seems like the `pembekal` value is not passed into the template context.

Comment: Where is the rest of that template and the view that renders it? We need to know what `pembekal` is at that point, to know why it has an empty `pk`.